# Jquery .html no changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've a problem in a JS function :

```
function showSingleArtistInfos(json_array) { // Affiche les albums et la présentation de l'artiste
    var json_artiste_info = $.parseJSON(json_array);

    var nom = json_artiste_info[0].nom;
    var bio = json_artiste_info[0].bio;
    var id = json_artiste_info[0].id;

    bio = "blabla";
    console.clear();
    console.log("variables assignées : NOM :" + nom + "\n bio :" + bio + "\n id pour image :" + id);
    // CHangements de la page
    $(".artist_name").html(
        nom
    );
    $(".artist_bio").html(
        bio
    );
    $(".artist_img").attr("src", "ressources/artist_" + id + ".jpg");
    $('#artist_infos').listview(); // Reload le thème
}
```

The problem is, in my console, "nom", "bio" and "id" are defined, but the divs content change randomly : sometimes it changes, and other time, no change, but variables are visible in the console.

Exemple :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4shQ.png : error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXAGx.png : no error

Edit : The HTML code (sometime works and sometime not) :

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">

<?php include('header.php') ?>


<div data-role="content">

<div id="artist_infos" data-role='main' class='ui-content'>


    <h2 data-role="header" class="artist_name"></h2>
    <img class="artist_img" alt="Artiste">
    <p data-role="content" class="artist_bio"></p>

</div>

<div class="albums_liste" data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
  <!-- Injecte ici -->
</div>
</div>


<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

Please help me !

Val.

Comment: Also show your html code or create jsfiddle

Comment: Done, but I don't think it's the issue..

Comment: Please.. I nedd help

Comment: Did you try wrapping your function in `$(document).ready(function() {.....});`?

Comment: It's a function.. I tried and "Uncaught ReferenceError: showSingleArtistInfos is not defined"

Comment: If you're not calling the function from somewhere else, just make it an anonymous function to run on DOM ready.

Comment: How and where do you call this function?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary to reproduce it_ **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the .done of an ajax query (this ajax is called onclick)

Comment: Try to use `$(".artist_name")[0].innerHTML=nom;`

Comment: Ok. New : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
So i think $(".artist_name") doesn't exit at the moment where I want to change the content of it. What I have to do to be sure?